# Access Denied s3cmd configure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When I am trying to configure my s3cmd using `s3cmd --configure` command I am entering the `Access Key, Secret Key and Encryption Password` and for the rest of the fields I just hit enter to keep it to the default as said in most of the blogs.

But after supplying the credentials, I am getting the error:

```
ERROR: Test failed: 403 (AccessDenied): Access Denied
```

How possilbly can I configure with the right soltution.

Answer (score 1):

There are several different things that could be going wrong:

1. You have an incorrect set of AWS credentials. If that is the case, then you will also not be able to use the official [aws client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html). Try using that to verify that your credentials are correct. Use

   > aws s3 ls

in order to perform the ListBuckets operation that s3cmd is using to validate your credentials

2. You have AWS IAM credentials that do not have the correct permissions associated with them. S3cmd performs a s3:ListAllMyBuckets operation to validate your credentials. **If your user does not have this permission associated with him, then s3cmd will fail to validate your credentials**. If you have an IAM user, try temporarily attaching to it Full S3 Access or Administrator access in the [IAM console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home).

Comment: Yeah when using the first command `aws s2 ls` I am getting `A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied`

Comment: This clearly means that the credentials you are using do not have the **ListBuckets** permission. Depending on what you need to be doing with S3, you might not need the permission to list all buckets. If, for example you want to read the contents of a bucket whose name you already know, then that requires different permissions and your IAM user might already have them.

Comment: so how can I get the required permission?

Comment: See link to "IAM console" in the answer.  If you don't have privileges for that, then find the person who does and ask them for help.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the command.
It should be
`s3cmd --configure`

Comment: Sorry that was not a typo in the command but while typing here.

Comment: And I could not have entered all the details and others which I told had there been a mistake in the command.

Answer (score 0):

Check your IAM user of which your are using credentials for *s3cmd* have correct access to a S3.